# Go AWS SDK "Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized"

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk-go

I am using the Go SDK to connect to the Kinesis Video Streams service. When issuing a `GetMedia` request, I'm receiving a 403 response with the following body:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

I am using LogLevel `LogDebugWithHTTPBody` to see this since the SDK is expecting JSON and receives XML, causing a `SerializationError`.

I am using Go 1.9.2 and have attempted this operation with both v1 and v2 of aws-sdk-go with the same result.

Here is my request:

```
POST /getMedia HTTP/1.1
Host: kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/2.0.0-preview.1 (go1.9.2; darwin; amd64)
Content-Length: 141
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/20180112/us-west-2/kinesisvideo/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;host;x-amz-date, Signature=60c625357b67c64caed32f5a0924882f26ffc776211801e94e7ecae84e7213c2
X-Amz-Date: 20180112T012511Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"StartSelector":{"StartSelectorType":"NOW"},"StreamARN":"arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-west-2:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:stream/StreamTest/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Length: 130
Date: Fri, 12 Jan 2018 01:25:11 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: 6f1701aa-f737-11e7-bcd5-c70a68e72add

<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To follow up, I have tried to issue the HTTP request above directly with the `Content-Type: application/json` header added, and the response is now:

```
{
    "Output": {
        "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException",
        "message": null
    },
    "Version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. From the docs,

"You must first call the GetDataEndpoint API to get an endpoint to which you can then send the GetMedia requests."